# AMD Graphics not detected

Tags: 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a Lenovo 330s laptop with a 4GB AMD Radeon 540 dedicated graphics. When I check the system details, It's showing only the onboard intel UHD graphics. How can I make my dedicated graphics to work. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Update #1

When I tried this code `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'`

It shows

[image]

Update #2

I have followed this link for installing the driver https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/amd-18.30/. The driver got installed without an error. I restarted the laptop, checked the about page. Still It is showing UHD.

Update #3

I tried to install amdgpu-pro, now the system is stuck on the ubuntu logo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is outdated. my AMD gpu is detected in 18.10.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first of all to not install the drivers coming from outside the distribution unless you really know that you need them. Ubuntu 18.04 is pretty new and the open source drivers for AMD are in great shape.

The situation is not so great for multi-gpu configurations though. But if you just want to use the AMD graphics card instead of the Intel one, there is usually a workaround that works pretty well.

In your laptop BIOS, you usually can choose which one will be the default active graphics card. You should choose there the AMD one. That will be the main GPU from now on and it will be the used by Linux.

Since it seems that you have issues with your graphical environment, I would reinstall the distribution from scratch if you don't know how to perform a cleanup of the drivers that you installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was at line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

You can find the grub file at /etc/default/grub which can be edited with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

the option nomodeset prevented it from loading the AMD GPU driver.
Once removed do

```
sudo update-grub 
sudo reboot
```